# Google Sheets (Excel): How Do I Iterate a Multiplier, Based on A Supplied Value

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I'm need to know how to achieve the following scenario using Google Sheets / Excel. I apologize if the subject wasn't accurate, it was challenging to put to words. :)

(where "x" is a variable supplied by the user; "y" is the multiplier which will be applied to another forumla)....

> If x < 10,000 then y = 1; If 20,000 > x >= 10,000 then y = 2; If 30,000 > x >=
>   20,000 then y = 3; etc...

How would I create that as a formula without having to hard-code every possible IF statement in order to increment "y"?

Thanks in advance everyone. I really appreciate any amount of help you're able to offer.

Comment: Are all the steps by 10,000?

Comment: I ask because if so the formula is simple `y=INT(x/10000)+1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the steps are incremental, like your example then the formula is simple:

```
y=INT(x/10000)+1
```

If they are not as simple as the example then using a table with a VLOOKUP is easier and will allow changes to be made without rewriting a nasty nested IF():

On one sheet put your table of thresholds and the multiplier:

[image]

Then a simple VLOOKUP() will find the correct multiplier:

```
=VLOOKUP(D2,$A$1:$B$8,2)
```

[image]

Comment: Both ideas were very helpful, however the VLOOKUP ended up solving what I wanted since I needed the multiplier to vary slightly (0-10000 = x, 10,001-20,000 = x+1, etc). Thanks a ton!

Comment: Then you could have done `y = INT((x-1)/10000)+1` @tSquirrel glad I could have helped.